# Any connection between the adjoint map that has determinant $det(\phi)^{(n-1)}$, and the adjoint map that has determinant $ det\phi$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, adjoint-operators, dual-spaces, dual-maps

> Is there any connection between the adjoint mapping that is introduced
>   while studying the matrices, and the adjoint mapping that is
>   introduced while studying inner product spaces ?

I mean, for example [Greub](https://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4684-9446-4) first define adjoint mapping while in the "Matrices" section as

[image]

and after that in the inner product space section,

[image]

but clearly these two map are totally different (just check their determinant), but nevertheless they bear the same name, so it there any connection (for a given fixed $\phi$) these to maps ?

Comment: The first one looks more like what is called the _adjugate_, which you come across when trying to write down a formula for the inverse of a matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix

Comment: No connection that I'm aware of, other than both operations reverse products.